# How can I change the color of a subset of text in a cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using Angular 2 and ag-Grid (NOT enterprise version).  I have some text within an ag-Grid cell. I need to change some of the characters to a different color.  I was thinking I could do this in the valueFormatter but am struggling to find an answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I was trying at add html tags around parts of the text within the valueFormatter function.  But really I have found no examples of how to do it and not sure whether its even possible.

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: I have no code to show.